# Share image in capacitor

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I made it possible to share the image in my chat, but the capacitor, when I do share, opens the application in the same window to which I sent the image.

How to make the telegram or whatsapp application itself open?

```
function shareImage(fileName, base64Data) {
  return Filesystem.writeFile({
    path: fileName,
    data: base64Data,
    directory: Directory.Cache
  }).then(() => {
    return Filesystem.getUri({
      directory: Directory.Cache,
      path: fileName
    });
  }).then((uriResult) => {
    return Share.share({
      title: fileName,
      text: fileName,
      url: uriResult.uri,
    });
  });
}
```

##### My app screen

[image]

##### Share dialog

[image]

##### My app screen after share (share in telegram)

[image]

I can't solve this problem by myself.
I'm using `@capacitor/share v5`.